# Win-Acme - Renew a Certificate: No TXT Records found

Tags: lets-encrypt, godaddy

This post is for a newbie, sorry for the stupid question, but quick long history, we have a dameware server proxy and the application have the certificate but its about to expire, we want to renew the certificate but when we try to renew the certificate we have a message:

[DBUG] [remote.globaltelesourcing.com] Attempting to create DNS record under _acme-challenge.remote.globaltelesourcing.com...

Domain:             remote.globaltelesourcing.com

Record:             _acme-challenge.remote.globaltelesourcing.com

Type:               TXT

Content:            "yUb2rMlywTZSrlJ9mm2QrmfkApK8KMfO2HA17NsAAhc"

Note:               Some DNS managers add quotes automatically. A single set
is needed.

Please press Enter after you've created and verified the record

**Question**: We need to create this TXT on Go Daddy? the question have sense?

**PD**: Sorry for my english, second language and if you are questioning, the guy who build and install the certificate on the application is no longer on the company and now i have the task of renew the certificate but as you see im new on this certificate world.

Thank you in advance.

Leo H.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to do this at your DNS provider, GoDaddy if you have your domain there.

But, keep in mind that the Let's Encrypt certificates have a very short life span and need to be renewed every couple of weeks.

You will need to change the TXT record for every single renewal. If GoDaddy does not provide an API to change the record and you need to do this manually this is not a sane method to validate your domain for Let's Encrypt.

See the [Let's Encrypt documentation for other validation methods](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/).

Most likely a HTTP challenge is better suited.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and yes, we created that record on Go Daddy and after that confirmation Win-Acme do all the magic.

Thank you again, - Leo H.